# \newtheorem in llncs creates problems

Tags: theorems, amsthm, lncs

I get this error `Command \theorem already defined.` when I try to define 
`\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` within a document with the `llncs` documentclass.

My minimal example is here:

```
\documentclass[article]{llncs}

 \let\proof\relax
 \let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{theorem}[Test]\label{thm:test}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think one has to load `amsthm` with the `llncs` class, which also has its `proof` environment. And for defining new theorems, there's the command `\spnewtheorem` described in the class documentation. The `theorem` environment is predefined.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The class already has its own `theorem` and `proof` structures defined, so your `\newtheorem` is causing an error since tries to define commands already defined. This class implements its own commands for theorem-like structures, so I wouldn't use `amsthm` here:

```
\documentclass[article]{llncs}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Test]
test
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Test]
test
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]